# Saving location to android app at installation time

Tags: android, installation, edit

I want to save a default location for android app when it is being installed. Location is selected by the user from a drop down menu which is provided in the app.

Once the user selects a location, the app installation gets completed.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading correctly you want an app that selects a default location for other apps to get installed? Or are you trying to install other stuff for the app from another source?

If so you could store a file on the SD card that contains the path or as a SharedPreference as a string containing the path.

If you are wanting the user to specify the install location of the app they are trying to install, I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: No what i want to ask is when i click the setup for app installation, it shows different locations for ex- india, australia, japan etc. Suppose now i click india, it is saved as the default location on my phone and the app setup is completed finally.  now whenever i click again, it should not ask about my location, but loads further activities from apk package..

Comment: Okay, based on that I would say you can use an initial prompt to select a location and then save the users choice as a SharedPreference and just do a check for that shared preference every time your app starts.  You can read more about SharedPreferences here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please mark it as the answer so I get the rep. =)